# Hacking around the default behavior of AddSearchProvider on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am wondering if someone has been able to hackaround the following :-

1) Making AddSearchProvider work without any user initiated action. For example, on loading the page.
2) Checking the Default option in the popup that is shown.

Regards,
harsh

Comment: So you're asking how to force a user to accept a particular search provider from one of your web pages?  If so, I hope nobody helps.

Comment: Indeed. The word ‘hacking’ is right. Browsers don't allow you to do this for very good reasons. No-one likes a search hijacker.

Comment: -1 - This is a grave violation of basic usability.  Hijacking a user's search engine is rude at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Requiring user acknowledgement is a security feature.  If you could do this, it would be a bug and the IE team would fix it.

If you have a legit reason to do this, e.g. you're a system admin and you want all your users on your (corporate) network to have some specific provider as part of the default install, then you can probably use group policy or IEAK.